# Avahi-daemon keeps disconnecting me from the network [Ubuntu 16.04]

Tags: networking, dns, avahi

I've been having this problem for a few days where my ubuntu machine was getting disconnected from the network and I finally managed to track down the cause to this:

```
Jun 11 10:40:19 nvidia avahi-daemon[886]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.1.200 on enp4s0.
Jun 11 10:40:19 nvidia avahi-daemon[886]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.200.
Jun 11 10:40:19 nvidia avahi-daemon[886]: Interface enp4s0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this to happen and the best way to fix it? I thought the simplest way would be to disable avahi-daemon but it seems to be a *very* resilient service for some reason.

I've seen it has trouble with .local dns addresses, but not sure how to fix that with my router (AsusWRT).

`sudo cat /var/log/syslog|grep avahi-daemon`

```
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Found user 'avahi' (UID 112) and group 'avahi' (GID 121).
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Successfully dropped root privileges.
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: avahi-daemon 0.6.32-rc starting up.
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Successfully called chroot().
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Successfully dropped remaining capabilities.
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: No service file found in /etc/avahi/services.
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Network interface enumeration completed.
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Server startup complete. Host name is nvidia.local. Local service cookie is 1297074648.
Jun 11 13:45:14 nvidia avahi-dnsconfd[855]: Successfully connected to Avahi daemon.
Jun 11 13:45:23 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv4 with address 192.168.1.100.
Jun 11 13:45:23 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jun 11 13:45:23 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Registering new address record for 192.168.1.100 on enp4s0.IPv4.
Jun 11 13:45:24 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp4s0.IPv6 with address fe80::9828:bc91:f5de:5190.
Jun 11 13:45:24 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: New relevant interface enp4s0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jun 11 13:45:24 nvidia avahi-daemon[881]: Registering new address record for fe80::9828:bc91:f5de:5190 on enp4s0.*.
```

Comment: I wonder if you are chasing the wrong wild goose. May we have a look at: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n10`

Comment: Can't edit my question above, so I'll post this here. This is what's happening: http://pastie.org/private/tn1qoocemxxodfqiwy7k2q

Comment: That's not quite what was requested: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n10`

Comment: Didn't look like it contained anything useful to me.  Check these out. http://pastie.org/private/irwgtq78t6dtjr6jetnl3w